# JpaSQLQuery with @ManyToOne -> where criteria not working

Tags: kotlin, querydsl

I use the QueryDSL 4.3.0
I have the entity:

```
    @Entity(name = "person_certificate")
    @Table(name = "person_certificate")
    data class PersonCertificate(
    @Id
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @Column(name = "expiration_date", nullable = false)
    val expirationDate: LocalDate,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    val fileId: String?,

    @ManyToOne
    val person: Person,

    @Transient
    val status: String? = null
)
```

I want to get all resources for a person id, and I need some data calculations so I need to use JPASQLQuery.

So I have the following code:

```
    val sqlQuery = JPASQLQuery(
    entityManager, MySQLTemplates.builder()
    .build()
    )
    val resultList = sqlQuery
    .from(pc)
    .where(pc.person.id.eq(personId))
    .fetch()
```

this generates the following query:

```
    select personCertificate.id as id1_7_0_, personCertificate.certificate_id as certific4_7_0_,    personCertificate.expiration_date as expirati2_7_0_, personCertificate.file_id as file_id3_7_0_, personCertificate.person_id as person_i5_7_0_
    from person_certificate personCertificate
    where personCertificate.person.id = ? and personCertificate.person.id = ?
```

As you see the personId is reffered as personCertificate.person.id which is not correct.

Also it's duplicated...

What am I doing wrong here?

It works with JPAQuery, but I need to use SQLExpressions.datediff which doesn't work with JPAQuery